# Averaging input from multiple input over a fixed amount of time (estimated)

Tags: input, datalogging, loop

I am trying to average input values for a number of inputs and have it then store those averages into a string to write to a txt doc on a sd card.

I am using:

```c++
// read 6 sensors and append to the string:
for (int analogPin = 0; analogPin < 6; analogPin++) {
  int sensor = analogRead(analogPin);
  dataString += String(sensor);
  if (analogPin < 6) {
    dataString += ",";
  }
}
```

to read the pins at the moment, but I want to change the analogRead(analogPin) to an average value and then use the averages to create the string.

but when I try to average the data I run into errors, or I get output that is 0 for something that should be higher (3.3V).

I am doing this to stabilize my values a bit better and remove jitter.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us your entire sketch?

Comment: take 10 readings, discard the highest and the lowest, then average the remaining 8 readings

Comment: https://github.com/MajenkoLibraries/Average

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function will average readings on an analog pin, include it and use it in place of analogRead(...) and it should do what you want.

```
int aveAnalogRead(int pin, int ave=10, int delayms = 0)
{
    int tot = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<ave; i++)
    {
        tot += analogRead(pin);
        if(delayms) delay(delayms);
    }
    return tot/ave;
}
```

in your loop():

```
for (int analogPin = 0; analogPin < 6; analogPin++) 
{
   int sensor = aveAnalogRead(analogPin);
     <<do your work here>>
}
```

Comment: There is almost never a good reason to add a delay.

Comment: With this though I have to run it multiple times, one for each input. Is it possible to have it also cycle though the inputs such as a loop within a loop?

Comment: yes use it inplace of your analogInput call above loop within a loop

Comment: so this:`int pin,
  for (int n=0, n<10, n++){
    pin = n;
  
  int aveAnalogRead( int ave=10, int delayms = 50)
{
    int tot = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<ave; i++)
    {
        tot += analogRead(pin);
        delay(delayms);
    }
    return tot/ave;
}}`

Comment: that's not how C++ works; you put this function somewhere outside your loop() on your sketch, then call then function. you don't need to copy the definition of the function to call it.

Comment: @EdgarBonet depends on what your sampling; one could remove it, or set it to 0, i just wanted to show how to do it with that in case its needed.